# Many to Many relation issue in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, many-to-many

I am a rails beginner and encountered the following issue

Models are setup as follows (many to many relation):

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :joinings
  has_many :attendees, through: :joinings
end

class Joining < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :attendee
end

class Attendee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :joinings
  has_many :activities, through: :joinings
end
```

This is one page test application for some users posting some activities, and other users to join the activities.
It is organized as single page format (activities index), and after each activity, there is a "Join" button users can click.

I am stuck at the point when a user needs to join a specific activity.
in the index.html.erb (of the activities), with the Join button code.

This will point to the attendee controller, to Create method, but I got no information regarding the Activity that I want to follow (eg. activity_id, or id)

Without this I cannot use the many to many relation to create the attendee.

What would be the correct button code, or any other suggestion to to get the corresponding activity ID in the attendees controller?

I tried a lot of alternatives, including even session[current_activity] , but is pointing (of course) always to the last activity.

Thanks so much !

Comment: I'd recommend renaming "joinings" to "attendee_activities".  Otherwise the name will become confusing as soon as you add another join table.

Comment: Sorry, the initial button code is:
    
 <%= button_to 'Join', attendees_path(@attendee)  %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have existing activities, and existing attendees, and you want to change the relationship between them, then you are editing the join table records.  Therefore, you should have a controller for these.  Like i said in my comment i'd strongly recomnmend renaming "joining" to "AttendeeActivity" so your schema looks like this:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :attendee_activities
  has_many :attendees, through: :attendee_activities
end

class AttendeeActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :attendee
end

class Attendee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendee_activities
  has_many :activities, through: :attendee_activities
end
```

Now, make an AttendeeActivitiesController, with the standard scaffoldy create/update/destroy methods.

Now, when you want to add an attendee to an activity, you're just creating an AttendeeActivity record.  if you want to remove an attendee from an activity, you're destroying an AttendeeActivity record.  Super simple.

EDIT

If you want to create an Attendee, and add them to an activity at the same time, then add a hidden field to the form triggered by the button:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "attendee[activity_ids][]", activity.id %>
```

This will effectively call, when creating the attendee,

```
@attendee.activity_ids = [123]
```

thus adding them to activity 123 for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here. I'm assuming that the *Join* button will simply submit a hidden form to the `attendees` controller's `create` action. So the simplest solution would be to include the `activity_id` as a hidden form tag that gets submitted along with the rest of the form. This `activity_id` will be available in the params hash in the controller.

The other option is to setup [Nested routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) so that the `activity_id` is exposed via the path.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the details. I will change the naming of the join table for the future.

My problem was that I could not find the specific activity for attendee create method. Finally I found something like this for the JOIN button:

```
<%= button_to 'Join', attendees_path(:id => activity) %>
```

This will store the Activity ID, so I am able to find it in the Attendees controller:

```
  def create    
    activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    @attendee = activity.attendees.create user_id: current_user.id
    redirect_to activities_path
  end
```

this updates also the Joinings (AttendeeActivity) table.

I will study about the hidden_field_tag solution, as is not clear to me yet.